# android: which is the best emulator configuration? and faster

Tags: android

I am using  emulator of ADT. I am using the default Android virtual device in my emulator. I created a version 4.0.3.

The problem It is too slow. Sometimes i am getting a loading click when i am trying to change.of fragment.

The code i am using it  is valid

What is the best configuraton of the emulator?

Which is the faster?

My actual configuration is:

[image]

Comment: Make it with low ram and low screen resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. It is much faster than default emulator.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), You can integrate it with Eclipse, and Android Studio
Really it is fast, easy to use :)